# Is there a more concise way to calculate the P value for the Anderson-Darling A-squared statistic with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, statistics

I have two bits of code in VBA for Excel.  One calculates the A-squared statistic for the Anderson-Darling test, this bit of code calculates the P value of the A-squared statistic.  I am curious if there is a more concise way or more efficient way to calculate this value in VBA:

```
Function AndDarP(AndDar, Elements)

    'Calculates P value for level of significance for the
    'Anderson-Darling Test for Normality

    'AndDar is the Anderson-Darling Test Statistic
    'Elements is the count of elements used in the
    'Anderson-Darling test statistic.

    'based on calculations at
    'http://www.kevinotto.com/RSS/Software/Anderson-Darling%20Normality%20Test%20Calculator.xls
    'accessed 21 May 2010
    'www.kevinotto.com
    'kevin_n_otto@yahoo.com
    'Version 6.0
    'Permission to freely distribute and modify when properly
    'referenced and contact information maintained.
    '
    '"Keep in mind the test assumes normality, and is looking for sufficient evidence to reject normality.
    'That is, a large p-value (often p > alpha = 0.05) would indicate normality.
    ' * * *
    'Test Hypotheses:
    'Ho: Data is sampled from a population that is normally distributed
    '(no difference between the data and normal data).
    'Ha: Data is sampled from a population that is not normally distributed"

    Dim M As Double

    M = AndDar * (1 + 0.75 / Elements + 2.25 / Elements ^ 2)

    Select Case M
        Case Is < 0.2
        AndDarP = 1 - Exp(-13.436 + 101.14 * M - 223.73 * M ^ 2)
        Case Is < 0.34
        AndDarP = 1 - Exp(-8.318 + 42.796 * M - 59.938 * M ^ 2)
        Case Is < 0.6
        AndDarP = Exp(0.9177 - 4.279 * M - 1.38 * M ^ 2)
        Case Is < 13
        AndDarP = Exp(1.2937 - 5.709 * M + 0.0186 * M ^ 2)
        Case Else
        AndDarP = 0
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: This is as concise and efficient as it could be in VBA, unless there is a built in formula/function.

Comment: my suggestion would be in the direction of a slightly more verbose code but more clear 1) change `Dim M As Double` to `Dim M As Double, c As Double, b As Double, a As Double`  2) substitute `AndDarP = 1 - Exp(-13.436 + 101.14 * M - 223.73 * M ^ 2)` to `a = -223.73: b = 101.14: c = -13.436` 3) act in a similar way as in 2) for the other 4 `Cases` 4) after `End Select` add `AndDarP = Exp(c + b * M + c * M ^ 2)`

Comment: @user3598756, is 4) supposed to read `AndDarP = Exp(a * M ^ 2 + b * M + c)`?  If so, I would still need to subtract the value from 1 for the first two cases and leave this value as positive for the other two cases.  I suppose I could add `d` and `e` as integers, pass a `0` or `1` to `d` and a `-1` or `1` to `e` and make the final function after the select case: `AndDarP = d + e * Exp(a * M ^ 2 + b * M + c)`

Comment: Yes. Sorry for mistakes but I didn't want to post as an answer and comments "environment" is quite narrow...